# Check if String Contains New Line character

Tags: c, string, fgets, character-arrays

I'm using `fgets()` with a buffer for a character array as I'm processing a file line by line. Will the buffer array contain the character, `'\n'` in its last position if it encounters a new line?

Does `fgets()` store `'\n'` in the buffer when a file starts a new line? If it doesn't, how can I check for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) scans and stores the trailing `\n` in the destination buffer, if one is present in the source.

Quoting the man page,

> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

So, to answer your query

> Check if String Contains New Line character [...]  when a file starts a newline

You can do, either

- `strchr()` with `\n` to check if the input line contains `\n` *anywhere*
- Check `buffer[0] == '\n'` for the starting byte only [*file starts a new line* case].

Comment: Both separate cases are caught at once with the line `if (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] ..`

Answer (score 1):

Yes [`fgets()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) does read the `'\n'` character if it's present, to remove it you can do this

```
char   buffer[SIZE_OF_BUFFER];
size_t length;

/* * we assume that file is a valid 'FILE *' instance */

length = sizeof(buffer);
if (fgets(buffer, length, file) != NULL)
{
    length = strlen(buffer);
    if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n')
        buffer[--length] = '\0';
}
```

what this does is check if `'\n'` is present at the end of the string, and then replace it by the `nul` terminator.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[100];
size_t n;

fgets(a, sizeof(a),stdin);

n = strlen(a);
if (n > 0 && a[n - 1] == '\n')
    a[n-1] = '\0';
```

You can check whether there is a newline character in the buffer as shown above and suppress it by replacing newline character with `\0`

Comment: If I were to hire you in my company I wouldn't because of your coding style, not your skills, they're ok, of course I don't have a company yet.

Comment: @iharob Please consider my skills because I normally use vim editor to do my coding and after writing all the code just I do `=` and `%` to indent my whole code... Please consider my skills :):)

Comment: You shouldn't make your editor indent the code for you.

Comment: @iharob Using the available tools when needed is an excellent skill :) :)

Comment: Formatting your code with a tool means you don't really care how your code looks. And writing code without any formatting is a bad thing to do in my opinion, because it probably makes you write faster but errors will be harder to detect. Also, suppose you are working on a file with `> 1000` LOC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. It will add `'\n'` at the end of the line if it encounters it.
If you want to get rid of it, compare the array index and replace it as desired using the follows. (change the `'\0'` as per your need)

```
if (arrayname[index] == '\n')
    arrayname[index]='\0';
```